# Unexpected log in Spring Boot application on OrderedRequestContextFilter

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, catalina

So I am developing a non-web server with Spring. It has been growing up a lot lately. I am a bit worried about the following logs:

```
`2017-05-18 11:26:28.791 DEBUG 2368 --- [apr-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7db0d8f7

2017-05-18 11:26:28.828 DEBUG 2368 --- [apr-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7db0d8f7`
```

And I am worried because I have seen this message before when I had communications problems. Nonetheless, this message shows up when a new websocket is opened or closed.
I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact reason of why this is logged. 
Can someone give a hint about what this message means?. Spring docs has no the minimum explanation about this clases

Comment: It is logged because you have debug logging enabled and that is debug logging from the `RequestContextFilter`. It does that for each request.

Comment: I am also getting this line in debug , how to disable this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe the cahe of the SpringBoot Application couse the unexpected log. When you **@EnableCatch** the SpringBoot Application, and request the same url twice, the unexcepeted log will appear.

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootCacheApplication {}
```